# How to nest and vertical align Kendo radio buttons inside Bootstrap grid and form?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui

I'm doing the radios as per [1] as the Bootstrap way [3] didn't work. The fixing `box-sizing` for a radio as per [2] does not seem to help.

[image: Broken vertical alignment]

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Heading here
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <form > 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2">
                        Group name
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1">
                        <div class="form-group fix-kendo-sizing">
                            <input type="radio" id="causeRadio1" class="k-radio" name="fieldName" checked="">
                            <label class="k-radio-label" for="causeRadio1">Label val 1</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group fix-kendo-sizing">
                            <input type="radio" id="causeRadio1" class="k-radio" name="fieldName" checked="">
                            <label class="k-radio-label" for="causeRadio1">Label val 2</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm attaching :

```
<link href="@Href("~/Content/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2014.3.1119/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2014.3.1119/kendo.bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="@Href("~/Content/bootstrap-kendo-fix.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

And the `bootstrap-kendo-fix.css` is

```
.form-control.k-widget
{
    padding: 0;
}

.fix-kendo-sizing,
.fix-kendo-sizing input {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Thanks!

Links:

- [1]: Radios in Kendo at http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/appearance-styling#checkboxes-and-radio-buttons
- [2]: Fixing `box-sizing` in Kendo at http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/using-kendo-with-twitter-bootstrap#nesting-kendo-ui-widgets-and-bootstrap-grid-layout
- [3]: Bootstrap way at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls

Comment: you're more likely to get a response with a demo - it's hard to fix these issues without reproducing them first

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the links, I had exactly the same problem and could solve it with your code and a bit of css debugging :

The `.k-radio` style uses `display:none`. The radio you see is the one styled in `.k-radio-label:before` and `.k-radio-label:after`.

Changing the selector to `.fix-kendo-sizing, .fix-kendo-sizing label::before` worked for me.

My `bootstrap-kendo-fix.css` is now :

```
.form-control.k-widget
{
    padding: 0;
}

.fix-kendo-sizing,
.fix-kendo-sizing label::before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Then I aligned my label by forcing its `line-height` :

```
.k-radio-label {
        line-height:inherit;
}
```